# ruby not working in all directories windows 10

Tags: ruby, rake, ruby-1.9.3

Here is my scenario:

I have a directory I want to run rake commands.
I install ruby 1.9.3.
I open a new command window in the default location of `C:/Users/Administrator`
I run `ruby -v` and get the response `ruby 1.9.3p551 (2014-11-13) [i386-mingw32]`

This is all good.

I browse to a folder and open a command window in that directory: `C:/agent`
I run `ruby -v` and get the response `ruby is not recognized as an internal or external command...`

Ruby is installed here: `C:\Ruby193\bin` and this is in my `%PATH%`

Further when I run PATH from command line I get this:

PATH=**C:\Ruby26-x64\bin**;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C
:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program F
iles\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\
Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\

But my environment system variables show this:
**C:\Ruby193\bin**;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\;

WHy would they be different? This is why ruby works in one directory and not another, I presume

Comment: thanks, i did try that. that didn't work for me. it did when i first uninstalled and reinstalled ruby. but a full system restart worked to correct my conflicting paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A full system restart fixed my path problem and as a result - no more ruby errors.